# What's the trace path of select() function in kernel source?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm wondering why 'man select' provide EINVAL for nfds > FD_SETSIZE.

But I use a sample code to test it. The FD_SETSIZE=1024, but select(4096, ...) not return EINVAL.

Anyone knows where to found the source code of select() implementation?

I use this commmand to found similar function, but it is not exactly the same as 'select'

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -exec grep -n 'select[(]int' {} /dev/null \;
./fs/select.c:396:int do_select(int n, fd_set_bits *fds, struct timespec *end_time)
./fs/select.c:518:int core_sys_select(int n, fd_set __user *inp, fd_set __user *outp,
./fs/select.c:617:static long do_pselect(int n, fd_set __user *inp, fd_set __user *outp,
```

And I grep 'select' in glibc source's syscalls.list file

```
grep select ./sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list
select      -   select      Ci:iPPPP      __select  __libc_select select
```

I still don't understand how to found the source of system call select() in glibc/linux kernel code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to find select() source code in glibc source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356123/where-to-find-select-source-code-in-glibc-source)

Comment: Thanks your comment, I use grep to found fs/select.c too.  But, I don't know why not the same as 'select' exactly.  Is there any common method to found out related code instead of the grep method.

Comment: As @MattBall says, exact duplicate, but that question's answer doesn't seem to provide the bottom line (which kernel function implements `select`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select is implemented in /fs/select.c and a copy in fs/compat.c compat_core_sys_select.

Kernel uses poll for waiting on FDs and it is used to emulate select.

glibc call the select system call that has an
entry point defined in:
arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl:142    i386    _newselect              sys_select                      compat_sys_select
arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl:23     common  select                  sys_select

fs/compat.c:asmlinkage long compat_sys_select(int n, compat_ulong_t __user *inp, compat_ulong_t __user *outp, compat_ulong_t __user *exp,
        struct compat_timeval __user *tvp)

This is the actual implementation.

There is also an old number of system call for select that is not used for ages. The difference is in the number of arguments select call takes.
It's source is in:
arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl:82     i386    select                  sys_old_select                  compat_sys_old_select
fs/compat.c:asmlinkage long compat_sys_old_select(struct compat_sel_arg_struct __user *arg)

You may want to find more about how vfs works in /Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt

Comment: I'm still miss. Do you mean syscall_64.tbl mapping *select* to *sys_select*, I found a line in select.c SYSCALL_DEFINE5(select...) is that the real entry point of select()?  So, if my program call select will call into kernel's select.c?

Comment: Yes the syscall table maps the system call to the function. For the 64bit case the SYSCALL_DEFINE5(select ...) macro creates a syscall function taking 5 arguments and the name becomes sys_select which is referenced from the syscall_64.tbl. So yes. If your program calls select on x86_64 ,when all the glue code is passed, it will enter that function.