# Cross-Compiling with mingw for Win on Linux a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, mingw

I try do compile a simple thread program for Win on Linux with mingw.

For that I load the [source](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip) and drop the source to my directory.
Than I wrote a makefile. For Linux it runs perfectly. But for Win I got many errors - some of them I can't fix already:

```
$ make
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O3 -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -FORCEWIN   -c -o main.o main.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -O3 -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -FORCEWIN   -c -o usleep.o usleep.c
------------------------------------------
clean up
make clean 
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog'
rm -f *.o *.obj *.exe
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog'
------------------------------------------
compile pthreads as static lib
cd ./pthreads/; \
    make CROSS=x86_64-w64-mingw32- clean GC-static
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog/pthreads'
rm -f *~
rm -f *.i
rm -f *.s
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.obj
rm -f *.exe
rm -f pthread.def
make XOPT="-DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB" CLEANUP=-D__CLEANUP_C XC_FLAGS="     " OBJ="pthread.o version.o" libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog/pthreads'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o pthread.o -D__CLEANUP_C -O3  -DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -I. -DHAVE_PTW32_CONFIG_H -Wall  pthread.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres --include-dir=. -D__CLEANUP_C -o version.o -i version.rc
rm -f libpthreadGC2.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar -rv libpthreadGC2.a pthread.o version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar: Erzeugen von libpthreadGC2.a
a - pthread.o
a - version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib libpthreadGC2.a
echo touched > libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog/pthreads'
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/mnt/prog/pthreads'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c ./main.c ./usleep.c  -Wall -O3 -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -FORCEWIN 
------------------------------------------
create object files
usleep.o  main.o
------------------------------------------
linking
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/pthread.o  -o possix.exe
./usleep.o:usleep.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
./usleep.o:usleep.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: ./usleep.o: Falsche Verschiebungsadresse 0x0 in Abschnitt `.pdata'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: final link failed: Ungültiger Vorgang
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [prog] Fehler 1
```

How can I fix the linking problem?

---

to Dayal rai

the includes of my headers are (in the order, which I think they are called):

main.c

```
/*#include <errno.h>    */  
/*#include <fcntl.h>    */  
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "./pthreads/pthread.h"
#include <stdio.h>       
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
/*#include <termios.h>  */
/*#include <unistd.h> */

#include "usleep.h"      /* um usleep nutzen zu können */
```

usleep.h

```
...
#include "unistd.h"
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
```

Could it be that it is wrong to include unistd.h for a windows target?

---

I additionally reduce the number of headers and change their orders in any possibility, but the error still exist. I don't know where it come from....

main.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>  /* Spezielle int-Datentypen */
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(FORCEWIN) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32)
    #include <time.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
#elif __unix    /* all unices not caught above */
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
```

usleep.h

---

with english feedback

```
LC_ALL=C make
------------------------------------------
clean up
make clean 
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog'
rm -f *.o *.obj *.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog'
------------------------------------------
compile pthreads as static lib
cd ./pthreads/; \
    make CROSS=x86_64-w64-mingw32- clean GC-static
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
rm -f *~
rm -f *.i
rm -f *.s
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.obj
rm -f *.exe
rm -f pthread.def
make XOPT="-DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB" CLEANUP=-D__CLEANUP_C XC_FLAGS=" " OBJ="pthread.o version.o" libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o pthread.o -D__CLEANUP_C -O3  -DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -I. -DHAVE_PTW32_CONFIG_H -Wall  pthread.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres --include-dir=. -D__CLEANUP_C -o version.o -i version.rc
rm -f libpthreadGC2.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar -rv libpthreadGC2.a pthread.o version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar: creating libpthreadGC2.a
a - pthread.o
a - version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib libpthreadGC2.a
echo touched > libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
------------------------------------------
create object files
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c ./main.c ./usleep.c  -Wall -O3 -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -FORCEWIN 
usleep.o  main.o
------------------------------------------
linking
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/pthread.o  -o possix.exe
./usleep.o:usleep.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
./usleep.o:usleep.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: ./usleep.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

---

I have remove `-DPTW32_STATIC_LIB` the from the CFLAGS and now I get this

```
LC_ALL=C make
------------------------------------------
clean up
make clean 
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog'
rm -f *.o *.obj *.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog'
------------------------------------------
compile pthreads as static lib
cd ./pthreads/; \
    make CROSS=x86_64-w64-mingw32- clean GC-static
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
rm -f *~
rm -f *.i
rm -f *.s
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.obj
rm -f *.exe
rm -f pthread.def
make XOPT="-DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB" CLEANUP=-D__CLEANUP_C XC_FLAGS=" " OBJ="pthread.o version.o" libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o pthread.o -D__CLEANUP_C -O3  -DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -I. -DHAVE_PTW32_CONFIG_H -Wall  pthread.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres --include-dir=. -D__CLEANUP_C -o version.o -i version.rc
rm -f libpthreadGC2.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar -rv libpthreadGC2.a pthread.o version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar: creating libpthreadGC2.a
a - pthread.o
a - version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib libpthreadGC2.a
echo touched > libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/pthreads'
------------------------------------------
create object files
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c ./main.c ./usleep.c  -Wall -O3 -FORCEWIN 
usleep.o  main.o
------------------------------------------
linking
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/pthread.o  -o possix.exe -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir='/usr/lib/gcc-mingw-w64' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-threads=win32 --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --with-plugin-ld --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.3 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'possix.exe' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/collect2 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o possix.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/pthread.o -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crtend.o
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_lock'
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_exit'
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_lock'
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_exit'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: ./main.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

It looks to me like a error coming from pthread *confused*

---

In reference to the comments by Gavin Smith below I have done some changes in the makefile:

```
$ LC_ALL=C make
------------------------------------------
clean up
make clean 
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog'
rm -f *.o *.obj *.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog'
------------------------------------------
compile pthreads as static lib
cd ./pthreads/; \
    make CROSS=x86_64-w64-mingw32- clean GC-static -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
------------------------------------------
create object files
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c ./main.c ./usleep.c  -Wall -g -O3 -FORCEWIN 
usleep.o  main.o
------------------------------------------
linking
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/libpthreadGC2.a  -o possix.exe -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22.90.20120919
./main.o: In function `thr_ausgabe':
/mnt/prog/./main.c:66: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_lock'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:66: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:72: undefined reference to `printf'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:83: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_exit'
./main.o: In function `thr_arbeite':
/mnt/prog/./main.c:44: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_lock'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:46: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:56: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_exit'
./main.o: In function `main':
/mnt/prog/./main.c:89: undefined reference to `__main'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:100: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_init'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:105: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_create'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:116: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_join'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:111: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:111: undefined reference to `fprintf'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:106: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
/mnt/prog/./main.c:106: undefined reference to `fprintf'
./usleep.o: In function `msleep':
/mnt/prog/./usleep.c:16: undefined reference to `__imp_select'
./usleep.o: In function `usleep':
/mnt/prog/./usleep.c:33: undefined reference to `__imp_select'
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

The symbols of the main are now:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm main.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_frame
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 N .debug_loc
0000000000000000 N .debug_ranges
                 U fprintf
                 U __imp___iob_func
                 U __imp_pthread_create
                 U __imp_pthread_exit
                 U __imp_pthread_join
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_init
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_lock
                 U __imp_pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000000000 T main
                 U __main
                 U msleep
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 p .pdata.startup
                 U printf
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 t .text.startup
0000000000000080 T thr_arbeite
0000000000000000 T thr_ausgabe
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 r .xdata.startup
```

I looking in the objectfile of the lib too an found the symbols a bit different to the main:

```
000000000000a9c0 T pthread_create
000000000000e6a0 T pthread_exit
000000000000b510 T pthread_join
00000000000024b0 T pthread_mutex_init
0000000000006c70 T pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000005800 T pthread_mutex_unlock
```

could it be useful to strip or rename the symbols from object files?

---

The actual situation:

terminal:

```
$ LC_ALL=C make
------------------------------------------
clean up
make clean 
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/win'
rm -f *.o *.obj *.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/win'
------------------------------------------
create object files
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c ./main.c ./usleep.c  -Wall -O3 -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -FORCEWIN 
usleep.o  main.o
------------------------------------------
compile pthreads as static lib
cd ./pthreads/; \
    make CROSS=x86_64-w64-mingw32- clean GC-static
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/win/pthreads'
rm -f *~
rm -f *.i
rm -f *.s
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.obj
rm -f *.exe
rm -f pthread.def
make XOPT="-DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB" CLEANUP=-D__CLEANUP_C XC_FLAGS=" " OBJ="pthread.o version.o" libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/prog/win/pthreads'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o pthread.o -D__CLEANUP_C -O3  -DPTW32_BUILD_INLINED -DPTW32_STATIC_LIB -I. -DHAVE_PTW32_CONFIG_H -Wall  pthread.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres --include-dir=. -D__CLEANUP_C -o version.o -i version.rc
rm -f libpthreadGC2.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar -rv libpthreadGC2.a pthread.o version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar: creating libpthreadGC2.a
a - pthread.o
a - version.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib libpthreadGC2.a
echo touched > libpthreadGC2.stamp
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/win/pthreads'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/prog/win/pthreads'
------------------------------------------
linking
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/libpthreadGC2.a  -o possix.exe
./main.o:main.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `printf'
./main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x6): undefined reference to `__main'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: ./main.o: bad reloc address 0x6 in section `.text.startup'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

the symbols of the object file

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm main.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
                 U fprintf
                 U __imp___iob_func
0000000000000000 T main
                 U __main
                 U msleep
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 p .pdata.startup
                 U printf
                 U pthread_create
                 U pthread_exit
                 U pthread_join
                 U pthread_mutex_init
                 U pthread_mutex_lock
                 U pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 t .text.startup
0000000000000080 T thr_arbeite
0000000000000000 T thr_ausgabe
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 r .xdata.startup
```

I really don't understand why he can't find printf and main....

usleep.o

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm usleep.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
                 U __imp_select
0000000000000000 T msleep
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000050 T usleep
0000000000000000 r .xdata
```

Comment: As per gcc rule `If any [static] library A depends on symbols defined in library B, then library A should appear first in the list supplied to the linker.` please check if there is any mismatch in order of source file and libraries in your build command.

Comment: To make your compiler errors readable by people who don't know German, run `LC_ALL=C make`.

Comment: I edited my comment with a suggestion about why it is still not linking. You shouldn't try to rename the symbols in the object file - even if it links it probably won't run properly.

Comment: You should consider winpthreads since you are using mingw-w64, which is more straightforward IMHO (`./configure --prefix=/usr --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared`, `make`, `sudo make install`). It is only available through version control, though. If you need a DLL, remove the `--disable-shared`. I always avoid building DLLs when possible because 32-bit DLL files and 64-bit DLL files have the same name. Unless you're careful, you'll end up messing up. Worse, any import library you link to will depend on the DLL not being renamed, such as you might do for 32-bit and 64-bit coexistence.

Comment: It looks like you are linking with the cross `ld`, which won't provide any required libraries (such as `libc`) automatically. Use the cross `gcc` instead.

Comment: gcc - in this case the compiler can't read the object files - unreconized format.
With cross gcc he gives me `undefined reference to `__imp_select'`

Comment: In the error message you can see that the gcc als calls the ld...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have created a static library file `libpthreadGC2.a`, but your linking command `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./main.o ./usleep.o ./pthreads/pthread.o  -o possix.exe -v` only links three object files and it is not among them. Try adding `-lpthreadGC2` or `libpthreadGC2.a` to the linking command.

If you want to check if an object file contains a missing symbol (e.g. `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock`), you can try running `nm libpthreadGC2.a | grep '__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'` to see if it is there.

I read in the README for the pthread sources you linked to that you have to define `PTW32_STATIC_LIB` when building - is there a reason you removed the `-DPTW32_STATIC_LIB` option?

Comment: I can't determine the format of the object files. nm always told `File format not recognized`. By the way. It's possible to make the pthread-lib with other choises. There are _dll with C cleanup code_, _inlined dll with C cleanup code_ and _inlined static lib with C cleanup code_. Should I use another?

Comment: In debug-mode I saw there all my possix-commands as undefined references. In the manual pf pthread it was say I have to use the CFLAG -pthread - but if I use this the compiler doesnt find the lib: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-pthread’`

Comment: If I use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm main.o` instead of `nm` it will possible to look into the object files :)
I will add these responce to the question...

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
./usleep.o:usleep.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
```

means that the symbol __imp_select is not defined. It could be in some other C file that you did not include in your final link step.

Comment: Yes, I understand it tis way, but there is nothing `grep -e __imp_select *` gives me nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356123/where-to-find-select-source-code-in-glibc-source

Comment: it seemed to me that's the right direction. But I can't fix it anyway. What I have to add do the compilerflags so that he find the lib. In the link above it was meant to include the `glibc` - but nothing happen....

Comment: The `__imp_` prefix is due to symbol mangling so probably will not appear in the source code.